# Javascript button scroll top and print

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a button whose function is to scroll to the top of the page and then print it.

My code attached to the button is the following:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(
    function($){
        $('#backToTop').click(function(){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500, function() {             
                window.print();
            });
        });
    }
);
</script>
```

And the button

```
<a id="backToTop">Print</a>
```

but the print method runs twice. I can't find a solution to prevent printing from running twice.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: That's because you have 2 selectors at the same time `html, body`. `html` tag will hit that animation first, then `body` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event will fire twice because of your selector `html, body`.

[What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) this might come in handy.